# Insert Trigger - 'EmpCode' value from 'Employee Registration'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 'Employee Registration' form (Windows Application). When the employee registration is done, at the same time i want to create an user. Taking the 'EmpCode' value from 'Employee Registration' and making it the value of 'UserName'. Please help me to write a trigger for it.

Employee Registration Table
Columns are

```
EMPCODE, 
EMPNAME, 
DESIGNATION, 
DEPARTMENT, 
DOJ,  
EMAILID, 
CATEGORY, 
EMPSTATUS, 
EMPMANAGER etc etc
```

UserCreation Table
Columns are

```
USERNAME, 
USERPASSWORD, 
USERMAPPINGCODE, 
USERTYPE, 
USERACTIVE, 
USEREMAIL
```

When the insertion for 'employee regstratn' happens, same time the following thngs shud happen in 'UserCreation ' table....,

`EMPCODE`'s value should be saved as `USERNAME`'s value. 
`EMPNAME`'s value should be saved as `USERPASSWORD`'s value.
`USERMAPPINGCODE`'s value optional 
`CATEGORY`'s value should be saved as `USERTYPE`'s value. 
`USERACTIVE`'s value is 1
`EMAILID`'s value should be saved as `USEREMAIL`'s value

Please help....

Comment: why would you duplicate information like this? Add a column to table 'IsRegisterdUser' ...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmployeeTrigger
ON dbo.Employees
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @empCode BIGINT
    SET @empCode = (SELECT EMPCODE FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @empName VARCHAR(50)
    SET @empName = (SELECT EMPNAME FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @empCat VARCHAR(50)
    SET @empCat = (SELECT CATEGORY FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @empEMail VARCHAR(50)
    SET @empEMail = (SELECT EMAILID FROM INSERTED)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Users (USERNAME, USERPASSWORD, USERMAPPINGCODE, USERTYPE, USERACTIVE, USEREMAIL)
    VALUES  (@empCode, @empName, NULL, @empCat, 1, @empEMail)
END
```

It may not execute as is, you might have to adjust some variable names in case either of us made any typos.
This is using INSERTED logical table which contains freshly inserted values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Mike.... I would like to ask u a doubt..,  when i executed that trigger, i got an error like "Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure EMPLOYEETRIGGER, Line 7
The name 'EMPCODE' is not permitted in this context. Only constants, expressions, or variables allowed here. Column names are not permitted." How can it be corrected..? I m new to sql server, so absltly no idea  how to solve it..

Comment: that would be because the original version was bad... I edited it, feels hacky, and there's probably a better solution, you'll have to replace types of those declared variables with your actual ones.

Comment: Y Mike ? Trigger created successfully... :) so much happy for that. Now lemme check whthr it works when the employee regstrn is done

Comment: Checked it, Mike. it worked perfectly when employee registrn was done... :) Thanx

Comment: @Mike Trusov +1, but why thare are so much variables?

Comment: Because that's the first thing that came to me... your answer seems better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmployeeTrigger
ON dbo.Employees
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.Users (USERNAME, USERPASSWORD, USERMAPPINGCODE, USERTYPE, USERACTIVE, USEREMAIL)
  SELECT EMPCODE, EMPNAME, NULL, CATEGORY, 1, EMAILID
  FROM inserted
END
```